# How to normalise plotted points and get a circle?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Given 2000 random points in a unit circle (using numpy.random.normal(0,1)), I want to normalize them such that the output is a circle, how do I do that?

I was requested to show my efforts. This is part of a larger question: Write a program that samples 2000 points uniformly from the circumference of a unit circle. Plot and show it is indeed picked from the circumference. To generate a point (x,y) from the circumference, sample (x,y) from std normal distribution and normalise them.

I'm almost certain my code isn't correct, but this is where I am up to. Any advice would be helpful.

This is the new updated code, but it still doesn't seem to be working.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot

def plot():

    xy = np.random.normal(0,1,(2000,2))

    for i in range(2000):
        s=np.linalg.norm(xy[i,])
        xy[i,]=xy[i,]/s

    plot.plot(xy)
    plot.show()
```

I think the problem is in

```
 plot.plot(xy)
```

even if I use

```
 plot.plot(xy[:,0],xy[:,1])
```

it doesn't work.

Comment: Show your efforts. Simply dumping your homework is not appreciated.

Comment: @cel Sorry, I didn't mean to dump my work. I have edited now and added my code.

Comment: You obviously haven't tried your code. There are many bugs in it that you would have discovered if you actually executed this in your python interpreter. If you show us a real attempt and tell us what you have tried and what did not work, we will help you. However, I can give you the idea what you have to do. You can project any point `P = (x,y)` to the circumference of the unit circle by calculating the norm of `(x,y)` and then transforming into `T = (x/norm, y/norm)`. This way it will have the distance 1 to the origin and thus lies on the unit circle.

Comment: thanks for improving your post. Apart from minor problems your code is correct. I posted an answer to help you finding the remaining quirks. For future questions please keep in mind that `it doesn't work` is a horrible error description. It's much better to describe what exactly is not working by proving the full error message or an image of the plot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connected lines are not a good visualization here. You essentially connect random points on the circle. Since you do this quite often, you will get a filled circle. Try drawing points instead.

Also avoid name space mangling. You import `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plot` and also name your function `plot`. This will lead to name conflicts.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot():

    xy = np.random.normal(0,1,(2000,2))

    for i in range(2000):
        s=np.linalg.norm(xy[i,])
        xy[i,]=xy[i,]/s

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5,5))
    # scatter draws dots instead of lines
    ax.scatter(xy[:,0], xy[:,1])
```

If you use dots instead, you will see that your points indeed lie on the unit circle.

[image: plot]

Answer (score 0):

Your code has many problems:

1. Why using `np.random.normal` (a gaussian distribution) when the problem text is about uniform (flat) sampling?
2. To pick points on a circle you need to correlate `x` and `y`; i.e. randomly sampling `x` and `y` will not give a point on the circle as `x**2+y**2` must be 1 (for example for the unit circle centered in `(x=0, y=0)`).

A couple of ways to get the second point is to either "project" a random point from `[-1...1]x[-1...1]` on the unit circle or to pick instead uniformly **the angle** and compute a point on that angle on the circle.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you look at the documentation for numpy.random.normal (and, by the way, you could just use numpy.random.randn), it takes an optional size parameter, which lets you create as large of an array as you'd like. You can use this to get a large number of values at once. For example: `xy = numpy.random.normal(0,1,(2000,2))` will give you all the values that you need.

At that point, you need to normalize them such that `xy[:,0]**2 + xy[:,1]**2 == 1`. This should be relatively trivial after computing what `xy[:,0]**2 + xy[:,1]**2` is. Simply using norm on each dimension separately isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

Usual boilerplate

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

generate the random sample with two rows, so that it's more convenient to refer to `x`'s and `y`'s

```
xy = np.random.normal(0,1,(2,2000))
```

normalize the random sample using a library function to compute the norm, `axis=0` means consider the subarrays obtained varying the first array index, the result is a `(2000)` shaped array that can be broadcasted to `xy /=`  to have points with unit norm, hence lying on the unit circle

```
xy /= np.linalg.norm(xy, axis=0)
```

Eventually, the plot... here the key is the `add_subplot()` method, and in particular the *keyword argument* `aspect='equal'` that requires that the scale from user units to output units it's the same for both axes

```
plt.figure().add_subplot(111, aspect='equal').scatter(xy[0], xy[1])
pt.show()
```

to have

[image: a circle]